# Automatically adjust ybar width (overlapping bar plot)

Tags: pgfplots

I am plotting a table with vertical bars and I get in trouble for large tables since the vertical bars are overlapping. Is there an option to automatically adjust the bar width?

[image]

Here is the code producing overlapping :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{pistonkinetics.dat}
x y
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  10
11  11
12  12
13  13
14  14
15  15
16  16
17  17
18  18
19  19
20  20
21  21
22  22
23  23
24  24
25  25
26  26
27  27
28  28
29  29
30  30
31  31
32  32
33  33
34  34
35  35
36  36
37  37
38  38
39  39
40  40
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}{width=10cm,height=5cm}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[ybar,mark=none] plot table{pistonkinetics.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document} black,fill=red
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a recent version of PGFPlots (at least 1.8) and your bars are equal distances apart, you can call `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}` before your `axis` and then set `bar width=1` to make each bar one axis unit wide.

[image]

If you're using an older version of PGFPlots, or your bars aren't all the same width but you still want to avoid any gaps, you can use `ybar interval`. Note that for this you need to add a dummy entry at the end of your datafile, otherwise the last bar will be missing (each bar in `ybar interval` needs a start and end value):

[image]

---

Code for first example:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{pistonkinetics.dat}
x y
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  10
11  11
12  12
13  13
14  14
15  15
16  16
17  17
18  18
19  19
20  20
21  21
22  22
23  23
24  24
25  25
26  26
27  27
28  28
29  29
30  30
31  31
32  32
33  33
34  34
35  35
36  36
37  37
38  38
39  39
40  40
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}{width=10cm,height=5cm}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[ybar,mark=none, bar width=1] plot table{pistonkinetics.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Code for second example:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{pistonkinetics.dat}
x y
1   1
2   2
5   5
8   8
9   9
10  10
11  11
13  13
15  15
17  17
18  18
19  19
23  23
24  24
27  27
28  28
32  32
33  33
34  34
35  35
36  36
37  37
39  39
40  40
41  0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}{width=10cm,height=5cm}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[ybar interval,mark=none, bar width=1] plot table{pistonkinetics.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```